# How can I test for an object being null inside a {{ }} in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code in my HTML page:

```
xx {{ option.selectedTopic }} yy {{ (option.selectedTopic == null) }} zz
```

When I run my application I get the following output:

```
xx null yy false zz
```

I tried removing the paranethesis around the test but it still gives me the same. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: where exactly you're doing it? here it is ok: http://jsfiddle.net/85cDr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but try:

`{{ !!option.selectedTopic }}`

I don't know all of JavaScript's syntax, but I recall that `!!` takes a value and turns it into a Boolean equivalent (i.e true or false), or something like that. Hopefully someone can clarify this better than me :), but I think the `!!` approach will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting that result, then option.selectedTopic is not equal to null, despite what is in between xx and yy.

however, 'blah === null' is what you want, as == will result in a match when the variable you are testing is anything falsy. 0 or undefined or the empty string ''

http://plnkr.co/edit/2aUMHEphnva9RylWIxNo?p=preview

The problem you are facing is that option.selectedTopic is equal to NaN, which outputs as null for some strange reason in angular. A true null will output nothing at all.